# Simple way to subset multiple data frames with pandas groupby or other function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` with two columns that I got with this command `result = pd.concat([Value, Date], axis=1)`

```
import pandas as pd

>>> result
                         Value      Date
189                        9.0  11/14/15
191                       10.0  11/14/15
192                        1.0  11/14/15
193                        4.0  11/14/15
...                        ...       ...
2920                       6.0   2/20/16
2921                       8.0   2/20/16
2923                      10.0   2/20/16
2925                       2.0   2/20/16
```

But what I need is multiple dataframes of all the `Value` data for each `Date`. I know that I can execute something like `x = result.groupby('Date').mean()` which gives me the mean `Value` for each `Date`, but I want the actual data in its own  dataframe that was used to produce the mean.

Is there another argument or function to simply get this data frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comments you can use seaborn directly to plot a `distplot` of all dates without any grouping or looping with `FacetGrid`. Here is some fake data for 12 days and then the plot.

#### Create fake data and then plot

```
date = pd.date_range('1-1-2016', '1-13-2016', freq='h', closed='left').date
df = pd.DataFrame({'num' : np.random.rand(len(date)), 'date':date})

g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='date', col_wrap=4)
g.map(sns.distplot, "num", hist=False, rug=True)
```

[image]

#### your specific data

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(result, col='Date', col_wrap=4)
g.map(sns.distplot, 'Value', hist=False, rug=True)
```

Comment: That's a beautiful plot and exactly what I'm looking for, but I'm having trouble replicating. In my case, I'm not sure how to a) get a data frame of my `Date` values and b) for each `Value` data frame.

Comment: I updated my solution for your specific dataframe. It should work exactly the same as only the variable names are different.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

you need a place to put each `DataFrame`.  Let's say you put it in a dictionary `d`

```
d = {day: group for day, group in result.groupby('Date')}
```

Comment: So then how do I call on one day's `DataFrame`, say for example 11/14/15?

Comment: `d['11/14/15']`  But if those `date` values are `pd.Timestamp` objects, using a string as a key won't work.  See, it depends on what you're going to do.  If you want easy access later I'd do `d = result.set_index('Date', drop=False)`  Then you access it via a slice of `d` with `d.loc['11/14/15']` and that should work perfectly.  However, that isn't exactly what you asked for.  You asked for separate dataframes.  What I just described is a single dataframe and an easy way to slice it.

Comment: Ok, that's helpful. What I'm really after is a plot of each distribution of values for each date using sns.displot() (sns being seaborn). For now I'll have to do them all one by one. Unless there's a way to automate this? Perhaps this requires another stack overflow question. Thanks for your help.